# Writing worksheet with pandas not possible / Workbook-error?

Tags: python, excel, pandas, dataframe

I would like to save a dataframe to a new worksheet in an Excel sheet with the following code / function:

```py
def save_xls(stock, content, filename):
    book = load_workbook(filename)
    writer = pd.ExcelWriter(
        filename,
        # engine='openpyxl',
        engine_kwargs={"options": {"strings_to_numbers": True}},
    )
    writer.book = book
    pd.DataFrame(content).to_excel(writer, sheet_name=stock, header=False, index=False)
```

But unfortunately, I get this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "C:\Users\Polzi\Documents\DEV\Python-Private\FairValueCalc.py", line 303, in <module>
    save_xls (stock, output, OUT)
    File "C:\Users\Polzi\Documents\DEV\Python-Private\FairValueCalc.py", line 36, in save_xls
    pd.DataFrame (content).to_excel (writer,
    File "C:\Users\Polzi\Documents\DEV\.venv\NormalScraping\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\generic.py", line 2357, in to_excel
    formatter.write(
    File "C:\Users\Polzi\Documents\DEV\.venv\NormalScraping\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\formats\excel.py", line 892, in write
    writer.write_cells(
    File "C:\Users\Polzi\Documents\DEV\.venv\NormalScraping\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\excel\_xlsxwriter.py", line 219, in write_cells
    wks = self.book.add_worksheet(sheet_name)
AttributeError: 'Workbook' object has no attribute 'add_worksheet'
```

How can I write this dataframe to a new worksheet in the Excel file?

Comment: Is it an `xlsx` (new excel format) file? If so it should work with uncommenting the `engine` section.

Comment: Changing the to_excel statement to
` writer = pd.ExcelWriter (filename, engine='openpyxl', ) ` 
helped - now the code works again